# GitVersion jumping versions for a single untagged commit

Tags: gitversion

For a single commit after a tagged commit, GitVersion Commandline suggests a version gap of 42 which coincidentally = `CommitSinceVersionSource`

[image]

The un-tagged commit should be `0.1.0-alpha.42` but GitVersion suggest `0.1.0-alpha0083` (i.e. previous version - 41 + CommitsSinceVersionSource - 42  = 83).

**GitVersion.CommandLine**

```
{
    "Major":0,
    "Minor":1,
    "Patch":0,
    "PreReleaseTag":"alpha.83",
    "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"-alpha.83",
    "PreReleaseLabel":"alpha",
    "PreReleaseNumber":83,
    "BuildMetaData":"",
    "BuildMetaDataPadded":"",
    "FullBuildMetaData":"Branch.develop.Sha.04c3569fa42b55388d8c133dbf0d3365dfda77be",
    "MajorMinorPatch":"0.1.0",
    "SemVer":"0.1.0-alpha.83",
    "LegacySemVer":"0.1.0-alpha83",
    "LegacySemVerPadded":"0.1.0-alpha0083",
    "AssemblySemVer":"0.1.0.0",
    "AssemblySemFileVer":"0.1.0.0",
    "FullSemVer":"0.1.0-alpha.83",
    "InformationalVersion":"0.1.0-alpha.83+Branch.develop.Sha.04c3569fa42b55388d8c133dbf0d3365dfda77be",
    "BranchName":"develop",
    "Sha":"04c3569fa42b55388d8c133dbf0d3365dfda77be",
    "ShortSha":"04c3569",
    "NuGetVersionV2":"0.1.0-alpha0083",
    "NuGetVersion":"0.1.0-alpha0083",
    "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2":"alpha0083",
    "NuGetPreReleaseTag":"alpha0083",
    "CommitsSinceVersionSource":42,
    "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0042",
    "CommitDate":"2021-07-05"
}
```

**GitVersion.yaml**

```
assembly-informational-format: '{DefaultInformationalVersion}'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'

branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag:
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: main
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: dev(elop)?(ment)?$
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false

ignore:
  sha: []
```

How to solve this conundrum ? :)